# How to get data is on a remote server using odoo

Tags: odoo

On a remote server I have data in this form:

[image]

```
A project contains one or more tranches
A tranche contains one or more units
```

On my class odoo, I added these fields:

project_id: this is a many2one field to select the project. I can get back the list of project from the remote server

Tranche_id: A many2one field to select the tranche. I need when I change the project, this field should just list the tranches of the selected project.

Entity_id: A many2one field to select the Entity. I need when I change the tranche, this field should just list the entities of the selected tranche.

Is it possible to implement the many2one relation on Odoo with the constraint that the data is on a remote server and consumable REST API?

Help me please

Kindly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
@api.onchange('project_id')
def onchange_project_id(self):
    res = {}
    if self.object_id:            
        res['domain'] = {'tranche_id': [('project_id', '=', self.project_id.id)]}
    return res

@api.onchange('tranche_id')
def onchange_tranche_id(self):
    res = {}
    if self.object_id:            
        res['domain'] = {'entity_id': [('tranche_id', '=', self.tranche_id.id)]}
    return res
```

It may help in your case.

Comment: Thank you for your reply,

The problem is when I want save the class (that contains project_id, tranche_id, and entity_id) this warning is generated

Odoo Warning - Validation Error
The operation cannot be completed, probably due to the following:
- deletion: you may be trying to delete a record while other records still reference it
- creation/update: a mandatory field is not correctly set

Because the data is loaded from a remote server, I can't save it on my class project 

If you have any idea about this issue please help me,